# Sum of the power of product of partitions

Tags: calculus, analysis

I was wondering if there is any asymptotic upper bound on $$
\sum \prod_{i=1}^k (a_i+1)^{-d}\,,
$$
where $d\ge 2$ and the sum is taken over all partitions of $n$ ($a_i\ge 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i=n$). Is it  $O(n^{-d})$?

Thank you so much.